# how to add a sqlite database with initials record to the android project

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I m planning to create a android app. And for a part of this project i have to have a Sqlite database including some record from the first time of installing apk file to the device...

For searching the cities of a country i should put data into the table of sqlite database from the first

I dont want to get data from internet or xml file
Just i want to know is it possile to have a table with some record from the first of installing this apk??

Is it possible to do this???

I know how to create new database and table but i dont know how to add a complete sqlite database with data in it to the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Just i want to know is it possile to have a table with some record from the first of installing this apk?

[Use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to package a database with your app and position it properly on first use after install.

Comment: Would you please give a simple example?

Comment: @HosseinMansouri: There are two samples in the `SQLiteAssetHelper` repository. Here is another: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Database/ConstantsAssets

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` to create your database? You can insert records into your table in `onCreate` records. This way the records will be available from the start.

Comment: I know i can add new records in OnCreate method but where should i keep all those data to read from there and add to the table???

Answer (score 1):

import your database into the assets folder.  Use in you database helper to access it:

```
getBaseContext().getAssets().open("myfile.db")
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to insert data in the onCreate method of your SQLiteOpenHelper class? this method just gets called the first time the database gets created. so you should be able to add date there

Comment: When there is 10000 records is it a good way to insert this huge amount in oncreate method... i think it takes to much time... even i dont want to keep a copy of database to the asset folder because it makes a apk very big....

Comment: you should use insertHelper which prepares the query. 100000 records is no problem for that. here you can see how to use it: http://orange-coding.net/2012/04/13/inserthelperandroid/ :)